# Would a compressor work if there are no equal items?

Tags: zip, compression, rar

I am starting to learn compressors, and the basic idea for generic compressors is to introduce in a dictionary similar items to reduce the size of the whole thing. A example with words would be:

> "I am in stack overflow.I am in stack overflow. I am in stack
>   overflow. I am in stack overflow. Hello. I am in stack overflow. I am
>   in stack overflow. I am in stack overflow. I am in stack overflow.
>   Bye."

So in the Dictionary we'd have:

A:"I am in stack overflow."

`AAAAHello.AAAABye.`

Would a compressor reduce size if there are no similar items? Or is it even possible for there to not be similar items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, text can be losslessly compressed even if there are no repeating strings, so long as the symbols appear with uneven frequency. For example if only 36 of the possible 256 bytes are used in a message, then it can be compressed to 65% of its size.

Yes, of course it's possible to have no repeating strings.

Comment: The strings is just a "method" to explain how a compressor works. So I am asking with elements. Is it possible? Or imagine: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" cannot be compressed, can it? That is what I mean, in a bigger "concept".

Comment: Those 26 characters are too short of a string to be compressed by a general compressor due to the overhead of the code description. However you can write a compressor just for lower case letters that will compress any sequence of lower case letters to 59% of the original size. A long sequence of lower case letters, e.g. several K bytes, with no repeating strings will compress to almost that same degree with a general purpose compressor.